# Unable to run vagrant ubunru 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Install virtualbox and vagrant, but when try to run "vagrant up" command receive this message

> VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
>   run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
>   instructions on how to fix this error.

"VBoxManage --version' gave me this:

> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
>        Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
>        headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
>        You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed. 
>   4.3.36_Ubuntur105129

linux-headers-generic - headers were on the spot

Then I run "dpkg -l | grep virtualbox" to get info about VB and got:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XKLb.png)

Unable to understand what should I do, reinstalled Virtualbox few times, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

as it says make sure to install the linux header generic package, run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: linux-headers-generic - headers were on the spot (they was at their place), everything OK with them